# Html overflow:hidden property in Microsoft word

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow, cpu-word

I m using Aspose to convert HTML table to Microsoft word table. The problem is the word table does not support `overflow:hidden` property. My code is like this in HTML:

```
<table style="width:509.33334px;max-width:509.33334px;height:275.0px;border-collapse:collapse;white-space:pre;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <td style="overflow:hidden;max-width:229.33334px;white-space:no-wrap;">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </td>
</table>
```

When I convert to word table I need the extra text to get cut off, but word is wrapping the text. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks and regards,
Amit

Comment: how does it look like in word ? You might need to specify `height` and `width` on your `td`

Comment: text wraps. Word does not support overflow:hidden property. specifying max-width, max-height, etc. also do not work.